# R plotly, normal cursor when mouse over the plot

Tags: r, cursor, plotly

In plotly by default when the mouse is over the graph cursor changes to "pointer", any idea how to keep the normal cursor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bit of a hacky solution but you can use `htmlwidgets` and Javascript to specify the cursor yourself.

Via `d3.select` we get all elements where the `cursor-crosshair` class is used and overwrite the cursor setting to default, therefore all other cursors are untouched, e.g. the resize cursor for the axes.

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

plot_ly(type='bar', 
             x = c(1, 2), 
             y = c(3, 5)) %>% onRender("
function(el, x) {
  Plotly.d3.select('.cursor-crosshair').style('cursor', 'default')
}
")
```

Comment: Thank you. Just for the records: If somebody needs a pointer-Cursor, use `.style('cursor', 'pointer')`.

Comment: This is quite an old question but hasnt there been an easier solution than this? Cause somehow it also doesnt work (also not in this example)